# Is #error directive crossplatform and crosscompiler

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I know that `#error` directive works at least with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/cpp/Diagnostics.html) and [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk.aspx)

```
 #if !defined(__cplusplus)  
 #error C++ compiler required.  
 #endif
```

But is it crossplatform and crosscompiler in general? Is it a part of some standard maybe?

PS. Because even looking at examples given in GCC and MSVC manuals one sees differences. While it works both with quotes or not, it makes a sad feeling, that it might be somehow compiler dependent.

GCC example

```
#error "Won't work on ..."   // quotes here
```

MSVC example

```
#error C++ compiler required.    // no qutes
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's any harm in asking this given that there doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Granted, the reference was quite easy to find. But SO is aiming to become a comprehensive Q & A repository and in that sense this question is contributory.

Comment: _"Is it a part of some standard maybe?"_ Yes, both the C and C++ language standards, as a simple find/`grep` through them would have revealed. Do we really need a canonical thread for every trivial "Can I do X?" type question that people think up? I see what you mean, but surely there needs to be a cutoff point somewhere.

Comment: It is standard, but it's not a macro.

Comment: @underscore_d: Well, there's certainly room for it. And this makes a change from all the reg-ex and UB ++i++ tosh that litters the C and C++ tags.

Comment: I don't have 'grep' easily accessible in windows. And I think it is not a garbage because in my workflow I would search it first on google and/or stackoverflow. Which means that probably a number of people would do the same. Than I saw that difference in VS and GCC manual. Which made me suspicious. And btw cppreference doesn't provide any peculiarities like quote marks

Comment: "I would search it first on google and/or stackoverflow" Seems you don't always follow your "workflow". I found a similar question via google on SO as the first match. And more in the others.

Comment: "I found a similar question via google on SO" those are different questions if you open them...

Comment: @MajesticRa off-topic, but to get `grep` and many other POSIX/`bash` style tools on Windows, check out MSYS2, which makes it super easy to use Unix-like tools and even entire build systems, and comes with a package repo containing many popular libraries.

Comment: @underscore_d off-topic. I know about MSYS2, moreover having it or WSL + MobaXTerm makes working with POSIX tools on windows almost as comfortable as on Linux. Not on the machine I was. And even having grep, opening google takes the same time as the console+grepping but gives better selected results on average IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. It's a standard preprocessor directive in C and C++.

References:
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/error

Comment: Citing a non-authoritative source for a question explicitily asking for a standard is not really a good idea. Why not link the C standard? IIRC, the C++ standard in term references the cpp.

Comment: Well, for starters, the question was tagged C and C++ before you removed them: I've now put back. Not sure we should make such changes without consulting the OP.

Comment: I removed them for exactly the reasons I mentioned in my comment. How does this affect my first objection?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from linking the C (and C++) standards in an answer. I tend to take en.cppreference.com as a proxy for the standards, and this particular topic lends itself to that.